# How to add two delayed jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am using delayed_jobs gem. Suppose, I have a ArticleController with following code

```
@articles.each do |ar|
    #call send mail method and add to delay
    #call createpdf method and add to delay

  end
```

and another class BackgroundJobs.rb

```
class BackgroundJobs < ActiveRecord::Base
  def sendmail(article_id)
     #code to send mail
  end

 def createpdf((article_id))
     #code to generate pdf     
 end

end
```

How can I add the send mail and createpdf methods to delayed job in articlecontroller code.

Answer (score 1):

First, i would create *class* methods instead of *instance* methods in `BackgroundJobs`:

```
class BackgroundJobs < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.sendmail(article_id)
    #code to send mail
  end

  def self.createpdf(article_id)
    #code to generate pdf     
  end
end
```

And then just call them directly in the controller:

```
@articles.each do |ar|
  BackgroundJobs.delay.sendmail(ar.id)
  BackgroundJobs.delay.createpdf(ar.id)
end
```

Comment: Since `BackgroundJobs` seems to have no other function than executing those 2 methods, you could consider converting them to services.